# How does GetChild work?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, tree, parent-child

I know it's a very trivial question, but I've just spent two hours on it and haven't progressed at all...so here it is:
Somewhere in my program I have:

```
UIElement bob = cible as UIElement;
```

(I had to cast it to UIElement to access a custom property).

Then I'd like to get bob's child (it's a button) to change one of its xaml attributes. I found numerous method to do that, `GetChild`, `GetVisualChild` etc... I still have no success, so if someone coul help me, that'd be great. I saw the documentation on msdn, and I'm learning about logical and visual tree, but it is still above my head...Thank you.

**Edit** some more information

The Block of code in which I want to do it is as follow:

```
object cible = FindName(nomtargetpad);//Retrieve a button that was clicked previously
UIElement bob = cible as UIElement;//converting it to access a custom property
MyClass.SetSon( bob, bufferson) ;//set this custom property for this element
```

Now, I have to find the child of the element ( bob or cible), which is an image, and set its source.I added this in my MainPage class ( and this is all there is in the msdn documentation):

```
public static DependencyObject GetChild(
DependencyObject reference,
int childIndex);
```

I then add this in the block of code from above:

```
DependencyObject joli = GetChild(bob, 0);//tryin to use what's on  msdn 
          Image belleimage = joli as Image;// Tryin to cast to avoid the problem listed below
          string nouvelleimage = "images/"+sons[bufferson]+".png";//preparing the new source
          joli.Source = nouvelleimage;//setting the new source
```

Sorry, all the names are in french, it propbably means nothing to you (unless bob I guess)
Despite the casting, VS reports that:
System.Windows.DependencyObject' does not contain a definition for source.

in xaml, it's easy, I have an Image nested in a Button.

Comment: Eric, instead of spending hours.. wouldn't it have been easier to look up `GetChild()` Method on MSDN to see how it works..? also can you show the current XAML , Template, Code..et....?

Comment: I did, but didn't know what to do with it. I tried the little snippet from there, and got close but still not there. I edited my Post to reflect it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a VisualTreeHelper class which you can use,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.getchild(v=vs.95).aspx

or if the child is inside the button template, you should use GetTemplateChild http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.gettemplatechild.aspx

Comment: I'm gonna read it again, but didn't know about GetTemplateChild. Thank you